# MyBatis dynamic subselect consuming value of the parent column

Tags: parameters, mybatis

I'm trying to pass column value from the root SQL to the subselect. The subselect should be build dynamically depending on the value of the column from the root table like in this example:

1. ResultMap

   ```xml
   <resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="org.test.MyType">
     <id column="id" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="id" />
     <result column="custom_identifier" jdbcType="VARCHAR"
        property="customIdentifier" />
     <result column="my_type" jdbcType="VARCHAR"
        property="findingType" />
     <collection javaType="map" property="additionalPropertiesRaw"
       select="selectAdditionalProperties"
       column="{customIdentifier=custom_identifier,myType=my_type}" />
   </resultMap>
   ```
2. Root SQL

   ```xml
   <sql id="select">
     select table1.id,
       custom_identifier,
       my_type,
     from table1
   </sql>
   ```
3. subselect in mybatis mapper

   ```xml
   <select id="selectAdditionalProperties" resultType="java.util.HashMap">
     select 
     <choose>
       <when test=" #{myType} == 'xyz'">
         value1 as "recno",
         value2 as "toxValue",
         from table2
       </when>
     </choose>
     where id = #{customIdentifier}
   </select>
   ```

In general I want to pass type from the root query to the choose statement in subselect in order to populate additional properties collection with data from different tables depending on the type value from the root. Would that be even possible in mybatis? Any idea how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot use `#{}` in a test expression. Try `<when test="myType == 'xyz'">`.

Comment: I've changed it reflecting to what you have wrote but it does not work too. It looks like the variable is not resolved/bind correctly. If I use the #{myType} in where statement it works fine and the parameter is passed but not when it is used in an expression.

Comment: I noticed another error: `<collection javaType="map" ...` should be `<collection ofType="map" ...`. If the problem persists, please create and share a small demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) on GitHub so that I can reproduce the issue on my end. BTW, what do you mean by 'does not work'? Is there an error or you receive unexpected results?